# Glassfish and JBI support, (SOA APPLICATION SERVERS)

Tags: jboss, glassfish, soa, application-server, jbi

We could see JBI in Glassfish V2 but it is not in V3, what's happening? Which application server is useful for SOA development?

can I deploy WSO2 on Glassfish or JBoss?

RGDS

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this answer is definitive, just based on my own experience with these systems.

JBI isn't a Glassfish feature (if it ever was its news to me). Its a (kinda/sorta) Sun community standard which has many implementations (ServiceMix to name one of several) that can be installed on any J2EE container (such as Glassfish to name one). Although it was once very popular it seems to have fallen on hard times of late, perhaps simply because ESB hype got swamped by the new wave of cloud hype.

WSO2 is much larger and includes JBI as one of its many options. By default its based on its own embedded Tomcat, but WSO2 claims its possible to run it on an external Tomcat (I never managed to make this work). To my knowledge no one has tried or succeeded to make it work on Glassfish.

Comment: As you know Tomcat is not a JEE container(EJB,JMS,...) so my question is how wso2 can work on it? and don't you think it is better to run SOA application on enterprise container(GF or JBoss)?\

Comment: Leaving marketing language aside (JEE container, enterprise container), servlets are a foundation capability that can be extended to do most anything by adding the jars you need. That's what WSO2 is; a tomcat base supporting most/all Apache jars plus WSO2 additions on top, including ESB and JMS and many others. Similarly for JBOSS and GF, which might or might not use Tomcat as their base. JBOSS does I believe, while GF does not.